# How to test for primitive types in F# and type cast without given type declarations

Tags: generics, casting, f#

This is what I consider a better way of **type checking** any type, by **pattern matching**, than all the rest I have seen.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a way to easily check for primitive types

I came up with it in my work making a Lexer and parser generator in F# without code generation and with DFA performance, and instant type checking.

Assume that we have some syntaks tree where you don't know how it looks or even which types it contains, but you need to construct it at some point in time, and before that might need to have a collection of different types.

That is against F#'s general type system.

I use obj which can be anything.

```
type Type = Type of obj
```

we define a function type that simply delay the work

```
Type delay = Delay of (unit -> Type)

let inline AnyType t = Type (t :> obj)
```

We define a function that delays the work.

```
let Delay f input = 
    fun _ ->
       f input |> AnyType
    |> Delay
```

and a function invoking the work

```
let Do (Delay f) = f()
```

now assume that we have some lexeme (string conforming to a pattern) and the type

```
type TYPE = INT of int | FLOAT of float | Error
```

with the function

```
let GetValue (Type t) =
    match (Type t) with
    | :? int as t -> INT t
    | :? float as t -> FLOAT t
    | _ -> ERROR
```

then we can do something like this

```
 let Float (str: string) = System.Double.Parse str
 let Int (str: string) = System.Int32.Parse str



let d = Delay Float "0.123" |> Do |> GetValue
let i = Delay Int "123" |> Do |> GetValue
```

without getting a compiletime type error. This will of course lead to the programmer checking for type correctness in the program, but that would be needed anyway